# Runtime error (crashes on input) in MIPS (using MARS)

Tags: runtime, runtime-error, mips, mars-simulator

I am having trouble with my code. I am currently getting a runtime error on line 28: Runtime exception at 0x00400044: address out of range 0x00000001.

The program is supposed to take input and return it in descending order.

```
main:
     move $s0,$gp           #get the intial point to save array 
     addi $t0,$0,1          # $t0 = 1
     add $t1,$zero,$zero        # 
     add $t2,$zero,$zero        # 
     add $t3,$zero,$zero        # 
     add $t6,$zero,$zero        
     add $t4,$zero,$zero        
     sub $t7,$zero,1            # terminate        
     li $v0,4       # system call to put the string
     la $a0,msg1        # 
     syscall        #
     add $s1,$s0,$zero  # copy the pointer to array in $s1
     entervalues:
     li $v0,5       # get the value in v0 
     syscall        # 
     beq $v0,$t7,bubblesort # end of string run to bubblesort
     lb $v0,0($s1)  # **HERE IS THE ERROR**
     addi $s1,$0,1      # move the $s1 pointer by one
     add $t5,$s1,$zero # $t5 stores the end value
     j entervalues
bubblesort:
     add $t4,$s0,$zero
     addi $t6,$0,1    #s1-1 -> s0
     sub $s1,$s1,$t0
     beq $s1,$s0,ending 
     add $s2,$s0,$zero
loopinterno:
     lb $t1,0($s2)      # first element
     lb $t2,1($s2)      # second element
     slt $t3,$t2,$t1        # 
     beq $t3,$zero,proximo  # 
     sb $t2,0($s2)      # 
     sb $t1,1($s2)      #       
proximo:
     addi $s2,$0,1      #
     bne $s2,$s1,loopinterno #
     li $v0,4       # system call to put the string
     la $a0,msg5        # 
     syscall        #
     li $v0,4       # system call to put the string
     la $a0,msg4        # 
     syscall        #
     li $v0,4       # system call to put the string
     la $a0,msg5        # 
     syscall        #
imprime:
     li $v0,1
     lb $a0,0($t4)
     syscall
     li $v0,4
     la $a0,msg2
     syscall        
     addi $t4,$0,1
     bne $t4,$t5,imprime
     jal bubblesort 
ending:
     li $v0,4       # system call to put the string
     la $a0,msg6        # 
     syscall        #
     li $v0,5
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be in the instruction:

```
 addi $s1,$0,1      # move the $s1 pointer by one
```

which does not what your comment states. It just puts immediate 1 in `$s1`. `addi` adds the second and third argument and puts the addition in the first argument.

You should have issued:

```
 addi $s1,$s1,1      # move the $s1 pointer by one
```

You do the same thing all over your code. For example when you issue

```
 addi $t6,$0,1    #s1-1 -> s0
```

you probable meant

```
 addi $t6,$t6,1    #s1-1 -> s0
```